# How do I access a multi-dimensional list of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I am populating a multi-dimensional (2D) list of NamedTuple structures, like this:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Halo(NamedTuple):
    ID: int
    axis: str
    event_file: str
```

I declare an empty 2D list:

```
halo_arr = [[[] for i in range(nhalo_bins)] for j in range(nperbin)]
```

I then populate the list with the above individual structures in a loop:

```
 my_item = Halo(int(IDarr_shuf[j][i]), axis_arr[j], evt_file)
 halo_arr[nhalos[hbin]][hbin] = my_item
```

I am able to fill this 2D list with the tuple structure, and access individual elements:

e.g.

```
print(halo_arr([0][5].ID))
```

but I want to be able to access the entire array of IDs (or any other array of the tuple):

e.g.

```
print(halo_arr.ID)
```

so that I can put that entire 2D array as a dataset into an hdf5 file:

e.g.

```
fh5.create_dataset("/Halos/IDs",data=halo_arr.ID)
```

Yet, I get this error:

```
print(halo_arr.ID)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ID'

I'm at a loss here, and may not be using the optimal structure.

Comment: You have too many undefined variables, you should make your code [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: have you considered using `numpy` for this?

Comment: yes, I should clean it up/rewrite it for this, but I'm looking for a quick answer, and the variables don't in the end matter.

Comment: How can I do this in numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an individual property inside that list of lists would require a more explicit expression of how to access the tuples depending on what you need as output.  For example using list comprehensions:

```
[t.ID for row in halo_arr for t in row]   # if you want it flat

[[t.ID for t in row] for row in halo_arr] # if you want it 2D
```

The first one (flat list) is equivalent to:

```
result = list()
for row in halo_arr:         # Go through the first dimension (row is a list)
    for t in row:            # Go through tuples of the row
        result.append(t.ID)  # add ID to flat list

# result will be [id1, id2, id3, ...]
```

The second one (2D) is equivalent to:

```
result = list()
for row in halo_arr:         # Go through the first dimension (row is a list)
    IDlist = list()          # prepare a row of IDs
    for t in row:            # Go through tuples of the row
        IDlist.append(t.ID)  # add to row of IDs
    result.append(IDlist)    # add row of IDs to result

# result will be [ [id1, id2, id3,  ...],
#                  [id8, id9, id10, ...]
#                  ... ]
```

Comment: I actually don't understand this, are the little t and big T variables correct?  It seems as if something is missing.

Comment: My bad, fingers randomly pressing the shift key.